# jQuery each-Method append items twice

Tags: jquery

I want to fill a select dynamically with options (coming from a textarea, line by line). But the following snippet appends the items twice. Where I have the flaw? Thank you for your tips.

```
function changeOptions() {
    var lines = [];
    $('#simulation').empty();
    var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
    console.log ('lines.length ', lines.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        $.each(lines, function(i, lines) {
            $('#simulation').append($('<option>', {
                value : lines,
                text : lines
            }));
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Why the `$.each()` inside your `for` loop?

Comment: Hi, if I don´t use $.each, I will not get the items line by line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `for` AND `each`? You did it twice! :)

Here is a bit shorter version of your code. I like `for` more than `each`, because it is faster in loops like this. And for things like you want to do, `for` is perfectly easy to use.

```
function changeOptions() {
    var select = $('#simulation').empty(),
        lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

    for( var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ )
        select.append($('<option>', {
            value : lines[i],
            text : lines[i]
        }));
};
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark is as success then. ;)

Comment: May I ask another question? If there is a text in a line like 'testname, testvalue, testcolor, ....'. It should only append the first text 'testname'. Everything before the first comma. How can I split it line by line?

Comment: Like you did before, with split: `lines[i].split(",")[0]`. Maybe use `trim()` too, to remove whitepace.